# How to use C# generics without wildcards?

Tags: c#, generics, wildcard, covariance

Over in java I'm pretty used to working with generics and the wildcard.  Things like: `List<? extends Animal>`.  This allows you to have a collection of subtypes of Animals and run generic routines on each element (e.g. `makeNoise()`).  I'm trying to accomplish this in C# but am a bit confused, since there's no wildcards.

Domain wise, what we're doing here is working with the SQL SMO libraries to collect scripts out of our database.  We've got a base interface type that is extended a number of times to script and collect different objects (table, view, function, etc  -- this is the T)

```
public interface IScripter<T> where T : IScriptable
{
    IList<T> CollectScripts(params...)
}

public abstract class AbstractScripter<T> : IScripter<T> where T : IScriptable
{
    ....
}

public class TableScripter : AbstractScripter<Table>
{
    ....
}

public class ViewScripter : AbstractScripter<View>
{
    ....
}
```

So far so good.  Seems like a perfectly sensible object hierarchy right?  Here's what I intended to do, until I found out there's no wildcards:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // auto discover all scripter modules, table, view, etc
        IList<Iscripter<? extends IScriptable>> allScripters = GetAllScripterModules(); 
        foreach (IScripter<? extends IScriptable> scripter in allScripters)
        {
            IList<? extends IScriptable> scriptedObjects = scripter.CollectScripts(...);
            // do something with scripted objects
        }
    }
 }
```

Now since `<? extends IScriptable>` doesn't exist here, what am I supposed to do instead?  I've tried a number of things, generic method, just using the base type, all sorts of nasty casting, but nothing really did the trick.

What would you suggest to replace the `IList<Iscripter<? extends IScriptable>` piece?

TIA

Comment: Are you over complicating matters ? List<Animal> allows you to have a list of subtypes and call a overridden method. List<? extends Animal> allows you to declare a requirement for a list *typed* as a List of a specific subclass

Comment: Right but because IScripter is generic with IScripter<T>, It will not allow me to say just IList<IScripter> ...

Comment: I guess, `List<IScripter<IScriptable>>` should help.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `in` and `out` keywords that enable covariance and contravariance.

Comment: @HighCore - whilst I don't necessarily disagree, a bit more info would be useful here

Comment: So you could use an `IList<AbstractScripter<IScriptable>>` right? Maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: IList<IScripter<IScriptable>> should work just fine

Comment: In c# rather than List<? extends Animal> you can have a List<Animal> and as long as your list is filled with subtypes of Animal you'll be ok.

Comment: @BrianAgnew: Maybe he's referring to this problem: http://smellsblue.blogspot.de/2008/07/why-java-generics-suck.html (possible "type unsafety" due to downward compatibility)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By using `out` and only passing `T` or other covarient `T` interfaces out from the interface, you can make the interface [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd469487.aspx);

```
public interface IScripter<out T> where T : IScriptable
{
    IEnumerable<T> CollectScripts(params...)
}
```

You then can't add to the result, because you cannot use the not covarient `IList` so add separate interface for when you want to add:

```
public interface IScripterAddable<T> where T : IScriptable
{
    //either:
    IList<T> CollectScripts(params...)
    //or add just what you need to, this is usually better
    //than exposing the underlying IList - basic encapsulation principles
    void AddScript(...)
}
```

Then just remove the `? extends`.

```
    // auto discover all scripter modules, table, view, etc
    IList<Iscripter<IScriptable>> allScripters = GetAllScripterModules(); 
    foreach (IScripter<IScriptable> scripter in allScripters)
    {
        IEnumerable<IScriptable> scriptedObjects = scripter.CollectScripts(...);
        // do something with scripted objects
    }
```

Comment: Almost, but it doesn't compile:      Error 1 Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'IScripter<T>.CollectAndScript(...)'. 'T' is covariant. IScripter.cs 8 33

Comment: Is it because it's putting things IN to the list as well as reading it out?  Should I return an IEnumerable instead

Comment: Yes, you can't do that, see the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd469487.aspx). You should [segregate your interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

Comment: By which I mean have 2 interfaces. One is read only, the other can descend from read only and add the writting capability. ISP may not be best link for what I meant.

Comment: Yep that now works perfectly.  I wish I would have seen this nice "out" keyword yesterday.  Also I am using the old style "_accessor" object over in the test project, which is now irreparably broken, so I had to delete that and convert it to use the PrivateObject which is probably better practice anyway.  Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 12):

Covariance is the property that "if an apple is a fruit, then a bowl of apples is a bowl of fruit". This immediately presents a problem: you can put an orange into a bowl of fruit. If a bowl of apples is a bowl of fruit, and you can put an orange into a bowl of fruit, then you can put an orange into a bowl of apples. At which time clearly it is no longer a bowl of apples.

C# and Java take two different approaches to preventing this violation of type safety. C#'s approach is to say that a covariant interface must have its covariance declared up front, and that the interface expose no method whatsoever that could be used to violate type safety.

Thus `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in T in C# because there is no way to put an orange into a sequence of apples; there's no "Add" method on `IEnumerable<T>`. There is an Add method on `IList<T>` and therefore it is not covariant in C#.

Java takes a different approach. It says "you can use this bowl of apples as a bowl of fruit *right now*, provided that *you don't actually add an orange to it*. The variance happens at *specific sites*, rather than being an overall property of the interface.

To address your actual question: if you are unable to make your `IScripter<T>` interface covariant in T because it can hand back an `IList<T>`, you might be stuck. But if you can make it contain an `IEnumerable<T>` then you might be in luck. Mark the interface as `IScripter<out T>` and then make sure that `T` is only used in "output" positions.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation Eric, luckily I can change the API to use IEnumerable instead so we are all good here. It makes sense.  Thanks much.

Comment: @JohnNewman: You are very welcome! This is a tricky bit of the type system in both Java and C#. (An interesting historical note is that my former colleague Mads Torgersen worked on the design of this feature in both Java and in C#.)

Comment: Best and most clear explanation I have seen so far on this! I have really been banging my head on this since coming from Java to C# but I think I finally understand how to work with it properly now. THANK YOU!!!